# Executes the element of a list in the file with a list of commands

Tags: python

I am new at pyhon, can you please help me how to write a program that reads in a txt file with a list of function, and then executes that function in the order it was read. The different different function in the file are:

add(x) → addition of the integers ;
Mult(x) → multiplication of the integers;
SQR(X)→  sqrt of the integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x=input('enter the value of x:  ')
mylist = []
with open("file_commands.txt","r") as fcommand:

    lines = fcommand.readlines()
    for m in lines[0:]:
        mylist.append(m.split()[0])

for l in mylist:
    if (l=='add(x) '):
        print('addition of the integers:', add (int(x) ))
    elif (l=='Mult(x)'):
        print('multiplication of the integers:', Mult(int(x)) )
    else:
        print('sqrt of the integers.:', ZQR (int(x)) )
```